# Watchman: failed to identify PDU: fill_buffer: EOF

Tags: react-native, watchman

I built a Android APP with React-Native. But when I run `react-native run-android` I got this error `Watchman: failed to identify PDU: fill_buffer: EOF`.

```
[3:42:00 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (2049ms)
[sane] Warning: Lost connection to watchman, reconnecting..
[sane] Warning: Lost connection to watchman, reconnecting..
2016-06-18T15:42:03,841: [cli] failed to identify PDU: fill_buffer: EOF
2016-06-18T15:42:03,842: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.5.0/var/run/watchman/kevin-state/sock! (Undefined error: 0)

2016-06-18T15:42:03,841: [cli] failed to identify PDU: fill_buffer: EOF
2016-06-18T15:42:03,842: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.5.0/var/run/watchman/kevin-state/sock! (Undefined error: 0)

Watchman:  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code 1 2016-06-18T15:42:03,841: [cli] failed to identify PDU: fill_buffer: EOF
2016-06-18T15:42:03,842: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.5.0/var/run/watchman/kevin-state/sock! (Undefined error: 0)

 ERROR  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code 1 2016-06-18T15:42:03,841: [cli] failed to identify PDU: fill_buffer: EOF
2016-06-18T15:42:03,842: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.5.0/var/run/watchman/kevin-state/sock! (Undefined error: 0)

Error: watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code 1 2016-06-18T15:42:03,841: [cli] failed to identify PDU: fill_buffer: EOF
2016-06-18T15:42:03,842: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.5.0/var/run/watchman/kevin-state/sock! (Undefined error: 0)
```

It also get when I start with `react-native start`.